# I can't start the javafx program. Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

Tags: java, javafx

Why doesn't my program start? I created a project in Intellij Idea, included the javafx libraries in file > project structure > +. then added VM options to run > edit configurations > modify options. but even so I get the error Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application. fix?(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuEkb.png)[error]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqLG2.png)[vm options]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/L96Fz.png)[path]

I tried to recreate the project, but the result was the same. how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Don’t add libraries manually.

### Edit POM for Maven to download, install, and bundle files

Your screenshot shows your project is managed by [*Apache Maven*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven). So edit that [POM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Project_Object_Model) file to specify your JavaFX (OpenJFX) libraries. Copy-paste the `dependency` element from a repository such as [this one](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx). Maven will download, install, and bundle the [OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io/) files.

### Use JDK bundled with *OpenJFX* libraries

Alternatively, install a [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) that comes bundled with the OpenJFX libraries. Then your app need not bundle. At least two of the several JDK vendors offer editions of their JDK products as a bundle:

- Azul Systems with *ZuluFX* (see [blog post](https://www.azul.com/blog/zulu-gets-graphical-with-openjfx/))
- BellSoft with *LibericaFX*

Read the documentation at https://OpenJFX.io/

### Let IntelliJ create project

Tip: Create your project using the JavaFX template provided by IntelliJ. See [the manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html#create-project).